# Ubuntu 19.10 freezes at logo the second time I boot

Tags: boot, freeze, amd-graphics

I did a clean install of 19.10.  I have an ATI Radeon card, which I'm adding in case it may be an issue.  It works beautifully, it detects the card, everything is super fast, great.  The second time I boot, it freezes on the logo screen.  I cannot hit any key combination to see what the thing it's freezing on.  On 18.04 I believe you could hit ctrl-shift-esc but that no longer works.

Can anyone help me diagnose the problem?

UPDATE

If i hit escape and choose ubuntu, with linux 5.3.0-18-generic, it boots fine.  The default is 5.3.0-23-generic, that appears to be what is freezing.  I don't actually know what this means, but I'm hopeful it's useful information for whoever can help.

UPDATE

I got a false positive, it is also freezing on that version, so it looks like it's just random.  It sometimes boots, but most of the time it freezes at the Ubuntu logo.

Thanks,
Kevin

UPDATE -

This fixed it for me:

https://nezhar.com/blog/fix-ubuntu-19.10-stuck-on-splash-screen/

Comment: Suggest you make that info an answer, not only linking to the explanation about using nosplash but also explaining that change, just in case that web page goes away....