# How to fix stuck boot after upgrade to 19.10?

Tags: boot, 19.10

After upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10, my Thinkpad x230 is stuck during boot. Sometimes, it works but most of the time I only see a loading icon (blue-ish icon with letter S) and I have to force a restart.

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191847/ubuntu-19-10-freezes-at-logo-the-second-time-i-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue most likely comes from splash screen. In order to enter your system you can temporally make your system bootable via:

1. Enter grub menu by pressing Esc during startup of the machine
2. Hit "e" in order to edit startup options one Ubuntu selection
3. Search for the line `quiet splash` and replace it with `nosplash`
4. Store it via ctrl + x and boot into the system

Once you are in your system, make the change permanent via:

1. Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` with admin rights and change the value for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` fromi `quiet splash` to `nosplash`.
2. Run `sudo update-grub2` to persist the change

Comment: There's a tutorial showcasing the steps with images at: https://nezhar.com/blog/fix-ubuntu-19.10-stuck-on-splash-screen/